# number of vertices in G

Tags: graph-theory

Let a graph has 6 components and 30 edges .what is the maximum possible number of vertices of G ?
The problem seems to me interesting.
Here each component may not have the same edges .Then how to approach the problem.
I only know sum of the degree if all vertices = twice the number of edges.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** A *tree* is a connected graph with no cycles.  The following facts are useful:

- A tree with $n$ vertices must have $(n-1)$ edges
- A connected graph is a tree if and only if removing *any* edge will disconnect the graph

If we are to have as many vertices as possible, then each of the $6$ components of the graph must be a tree.

---

Suppose that the components have $E_1,E_2,\dots,E_6$ many edges respectively.  The total number of edges is 30, which is to say that
$$
E_1 + E_2 +  \cdots + E_6 = 30
$$
Since each component is a tree, the number of vertices in the $i$th component must be $E_i + 1$.  So, the total number of vertices is
$$
(E_1 + 1) + (E_2 + 1) + \cdots + (E_6 + 1)
$$
which is necessarily $36$ (why?).

Comment: I know all these facts.but I am sorry to say i cannot see how r these being used

Comment: Because each component is a tree, knowing the total number of edges is enough to figure out the total number of vertices.  You're going to have to figure it out from there.

Comment: Here total no of vertices = 60.then?

Comment: No.  Let's start here: why does the total number of vertices need to be **less** than 30?

Comment: @mathisfun If your graph has 6 components, then by drawing 5 more edges you can make it connected, right? So if you started with n vertices, 30 edges, and 6 components, you now have a connected graph with n vertices and 35 edges. What's the most vertices a connected graph with 35 edges can have? How many vertices does a tree with 35 edges have?

Comment: @bof you're right;  I had the math backwards.

Comment: @mathisfun see my latest edit

Comment: Now quite clear